# How to retrieve predicates and objects of an RDF document in SPARQL with labels?

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I am using DBpedia endpoint using Jena. I am sending SPARQL query to retrieve the objects and predicates of an object (say for example, http://dbpedia.org/page/London). How to get the following two result sets:-

1. All predicates and objects of London in **labels** as shown here (http://dbpedia.org/page/London).
2. All predicates and objects of London converted into **URIs**.

```js
String sparqlQueryString1 = "PREFIX owl: <w3.org/2002/07/owl#>" +
 "PREFIX xsd:<w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>" +
 "PREFIX rdfs: <w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>" +
 "PREFIX rdf: <w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" +
 "PREFIX foaf: <xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>" +
 "PREFIX dc: <purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>" + 
 "PREFIX dbr: <dbpedia.org/resource/>" +
 "PREFIX dbpedia2: <dbpedia.org/property/>" +
 "PREFIX dbo: <dbpedia.org/ontology/>" +
 "select ?p ?o where { dbr:London ?p ?o}"
```

Comment: I'm not a user of these tools, but would one need to know the query and other info to be able to help you?

Comment: Please show current query and code.

Comment: 'String sparqlQueryString1 = "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"+
"PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"+
"PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"+
"PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
"PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+
"PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>"+
"PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>"+
"PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>"+
"PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>"+
"select ?p ?o where {"+
"  dbr:London ?p ?o "+
"}";'

Comment: @AKSW The code has been given.

Comment: Ok, next time please add the code to your question. It's unreadable in a comment. And in your case, it's better to just show the SPARQL query as your code does nothing that is relevant for the question.

Comment: So, your question is to get the labels of the objects? In that case, you have to add another triple pattern `?o rdfs:label ?l` and select `?l` - maybe you should also add a filter on the language, e.g. `FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?l),'en'))` . Note that this way will not return literal values as those do not have a label. To solve this, you would have to put the triple pattern into an OPTIONAL clause.

Comment: But this question has been asked several times here, I'm wondering why you did not find it here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @AKSW The problem however is that all the list of predicates labels are not being retrieved. Some of them are always missing. Should I be adding more namespace ? It is quite confusing. I have seen the questions asked here however there is no proper reply.

Comment: Can you clarify e.g. with an example which one is not retrieved? Note, that what I suggested works only on i) URIs ii) that have a label of English language iii) that is contained in the current knowledge base.